# Adding and Filling rows in a df under conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a df like this:

```
Timestamp                                 Time  Power    Total Energy              ID     Energy
2020-04-09 06:45:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500       5636690.0               1      140.0    
2020-04-09 06:46:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500       5636710.0               1      160.0    
2020-04-09 06:47:00                        NaT    NaN             NaN             NaN        NaN    
2020-04-09 06:48:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500       5636960.0               1      410.0
2020-04-09 06:49:00                        NaT    NaN             NaN             NaN        NaN
2020-04-09 06:50:00                        NaT    NaN             NaN             NaN        NaN
2020-04-09 06:51:00                        NaT    NaN             NaN             NaN        NaN
...                                        ...    ...             ...             ...        ...
2020-04-30 23:55:00 2020-04-29 16:30:38.559871   7500      18569270.0               5      100.0
2020-04-30 23:54:00                        NaT    NaN             NaN             NaN        NaN
2020-04-30 23:55:00 2020-04-29 16:30:38.559871   7500      18569370.0               5      180.0
```

i have to adjust/add some values:

1. Add rows for df['Time'] > df['Timestamp']: df['Timestamp'] in 1 minute intervall; df['Time'] = entry of df['Time']; df['Power'] = df['Energy'] / (delta t (=difference between time and existing timestamp (in hours))); df['Total Energy'], df['ID'] and df['Energy'] lik df['time']
2. Filling the NaN/NaT-values in the area where time does not change (with bfill or ffill)
3. Filling the NaN/Nat-values between two different df['Time'] entrys with 0, respectively df['Total Energy'] with the last entry (ffill)

Expected outcome:

```
Timestamp                                 Time  Power    Total Energy              ID     Energy
2020-04-09 06:41:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   2100       5636690.0               1      140.0    
2020-04-09 06:42:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   2100       5636690.0               1      140.0    
2020-04-09 06:43:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   2100       5636690.0               1      140.0    
2020-04-09 06:44:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   2100       5636690.0               1      140.0
2020-04-09 06:45:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500       5636690.0               1      140.0    
2020-04-09 06:46:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500       5636710.0               1      160.0    
2020-04-09 06:47:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500       5636710.0               1      160.0    
2020-04-09 06:48:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500       5636960.0               1      410.0
2020-04-09 06:49:00                         -       0       5636960.0               -          0
2020-04-09 06:50:00                         -       0       5636960.0               -          0
2020-04-09 06:51:00                         -       0       5636960.0               -          0
...                                        ...    ...             ...             ...        ...
2020-04-30 23:55:00 2020-04-29 16:30:38.559871   7500      18569270.0               5      100.0
2020-04-30 23:54:00 2020-04-29 16:30:38.559871   7500      18569270.0               5      100.0
2020-04-30 23:55:00 2020-04-29 16:30:38.559871   7500      18569370.0               5      180.0
```

i think the solution will have something to do with ffill() under certain conditions, unfortunately i do not know how to formulate this.

**EDIT:
Here a sample of my code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ["2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719","2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719", 'NaT', "2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719", 'NaT', 'NaT', 'NaT', '2020-04-09 16:50:38.559871', 'NaT', '2020-04-29 16:50:38.559871'],
              "Power": [7500, 6000, 'NaN', 6000, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 3600, 'NaN', 4200],
              "Total Energy": [5000, 5100, 'NaN', 5300, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 5360, 'NaN', 5500],
              "ID": [1, 1, 'NaN', 1, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 2, 'NaN', 2],
              "Energy": [500, 600, 'NaN', 800, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 60, 'NaN', 200]},
              index=pd.date_range(start = "2020-04-09 6:45", periods = 10, freq = 'T'))

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Power'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Power'], errors = 'coerce')
df['Total Energy'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total Energy'], errors = 'coerce')
df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors = 'coerce')
df['Energy'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Energy'], errors = 'coerce')

df
```

Excpected outcome:

```
                    Time                       Power    Total Energy    ID  Energy
2020-04-09 06:41:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   0      4500.0          1.0 0
2020-04-09 06:42:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500.0 4625.0          1.0 125.0
2020-04-09 06:43:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500.0 4750.0          1.0 250.0
2020-04-09 06:44:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500.0 4875.0          1.0 375.0
2020-04-09 06:45:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   7500.0 5000.0          1.0 500.0
2020-04-09 06:46:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   6000.0 5100.0          1.0 600.0
2020-04-09 06:47:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   6000.0 5200.0          1.0 700.0
2020-04-09 06:48:00 2020-04-09 06:40:40.559719   6000.0 5300.0          1.0 800.0
2020-04-09 06:49:00 -                           0       5300.0          -   0
2020-04-09 06:50:00 -                           0       5300.0          -   0
2020-04-09 06:51:00 2020-04-09 16:50:38.559871  0       5300.0          2.0 0
2020-04-09 06:52:00 2020-04-09 16:50:38.559871  3600.0  5360.0          2.0 60.0
2020-04-09 06:53:00 2020-04-09 16:50:38.559871  4200.0  5430.0          2.0 130.0
2020-04-09 06:54:00 2020-04-29 16:50:38.559871  4200.0  5500.0          2.0 200.0
```

1. df['Time']: create new rows until df['Timestamp'] = df['Time']
2. Filling the new rows: df['Energy'] = 0 for the first line, than filling it linearly; df['Power'] = 0 for the first line, than df['Power'] = df['Energy']/(1/60); df['Time'] and df['ID'] fill with bfill(); df['Total Energy'] = Total Sum of df['Energy']
3. The lines between two different Times: Filling as in the expected outcome
4. The NaN-values in a Time-Series (for example @2020-04-09 06:47:00): df['Time'] and df['ID'] with ffill(); df['Energy'] = difference between the existing lines (if there are more NaN-Lines --> interpolate lineraly); df['Total Energy'] = old value + df['Energy']; df['Power'] = df['Energy']/(1/60)

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that a few different functions may be necessary:

1. **delta t:** Can use [shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get lead or lag values and then can calculate the difference.
2. To fill the NaN/NaT values, can use [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
   **bfill:** `df['Column'].fillna(val, method='bfill')`
   **ffill:** `df['Column'].fillna(val, method='ffill')`
3. Can use fillna as above. Following that, can overwrite the column with new values based on condition:
   `np.where(condition, value if condition met, value if condition not met)`

For instance, to create total energy column once energy column is complete, you could use:

```
# 1. First fill na with ffill method'
df['Total Energy'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
# 2. Find deltas
df['energy_delta'] = df['Energy'] - df['Energy'].shift(1)
df['t_energy_delta'] = df['Total Energy'] - df['Total Energy'].shift(1)
# 3. Correct total_energy column to take into account delta
df['Total Energy'] = np.where(df['energy_delta']>df['t_energy_delta'], df['Total Energy']+df['energy_delta'], df['Total Energy'])
```

This is bit verbose but I think it will do the job. Probably there is a better way.

Comment: ok, but how can I include here the different conditions that the nan values between different time entries should be treated differently than within a section (time entry remains the same)

Comment: Hi Vini, I have updated my answer to include more details. If you could provide a syntax to create a small dataset that represents your challenge, it would be easier to help with exact syntax. Otherwise, my current answer is more like a general guideline.

Comment: Hi Zolzaya, I've edited my post and added a code, I hope this helps. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Thanks Vini. I find it quite to hard to make sense of the logic. It looks that your description of logic and expected output are not consistent. For instance: df['Power'] = df['Energy']/(1/60) condition doesn't seem to hold in the expected output. In the first row, the raw data has 6000 in Power but in expected output it changed to 7500. Are the non-missing values also meant to change? Sample data starts from 6:45 but expected output start bit earlier. I think you may have to make what you want to accomplish and where you need help more clear.

Comment: Hey Zalzaya, thanks for spending time on my problem. You're right, the first 6000 at df['power'] were a typing error (I mended it). the second thing you bring up with the dates before 6:45 is exactly the same. I want to add the missing data between df['Time'] and the index, or if the lines already exist, fill them accordingly. More precisely, the lines should be filled from the corresponding entry for df['Time'] ( df['Time'] == 06:40:40 --> lines from df.index = 06:41:00 should be filled accordingly).

Comment: But for me it is basically more important to fill the lines from which there is a df['Time'] entry. Adding the missing lines at the beginning of the df is not so important.

Comment: From 6:52 to 6:54, why did total energy increment by 100 when energy increment by 70?

Comment: I am really sorry, I am writing the table by hand and I think I have made some mistakes here.

Comment: No worries, I think logic for total energy column is clear - I have updated my answer to include sample script. So, now for energy column, could you please explain why 6:49-6:51 is 0?

Comment: the data are different events with different ids. no "event" is taking place in the mentioned period, therefore the event specific values should be set to 0 / '-' and only the general parameters (like total energy) should be continued.

Comment: Thanks for the Code for df['Total_Energy'], but isn't it the same like only ´fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)´?
And do you have an idea how I can access the periods without an event and set them to 0 (also afterwards) - for the periods that were addressed before?